# Youtube Search API v3 - filter by duration

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Trying to filter using "videoDuration" parameter but looks like i can select just one of the options and not multiple, am i right or there is an alternative i can get all songs until 20 minutes duration include "short" one?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Good question. 
I think you are right and can only request a single videoDuration.
You'll have to make separate requests for 'short' and 'medium' durations and merge the results together in your script.

Comment: Yes, but then i'll lose the original ordering of the API.. too bad ;) but thanks anyway...

Comment: any chance to orderBy duration? from short to long?

Comment: You'll have all the video data, so you can order them however you wish in your script.